# MQTT connection with tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create an MQTT connection with tokio and the codec provided in the mqtt_v5 crate. My code does not compile, and I don't understand why. Here is what I have written so far, the send code might not be correct.

```rust
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_util::codec::Framed;
use tokio_util::codec::Decoder;
use std::net::SocketAddrV4;
use mqtt_v5::types::Packet as MqttPacket;
use mqtt_v5::codec::MqttCodec;
use futures_sink::Sink;
use futures_core::stream::Stream;

struct MqttConn {
    inner: Framed<TcpStream, MqttCodec>,
}

impl MqttConn {
    async fn new(addr: SocketAddrV4) -> MqttConn {
        let tcp = TcpStream::connect(addr).await.expect("cannot connect to mqtt");
        MqttConn { inner: MqttCodec::new().framed(tcp) } 
    }

    async fn handle(&self, handler: &dyn Fn(&MqttConn, MqttPacket) -> ()) {
        while let Some(p) = self.inner.next().await {
            handler(self, p)
        }
    }

    async fn send(&self, p: MqttPacket) {
        self.inner.start_send(p);
    }
}
```

I get these errors from the compiler:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `framed` found for struct `MqttCodec` in the current scope
  --> src/mqtt.rs:17:44
   |
17 |         MqttConn { inner: MqttCodec::new().framed(tcp) } 
   |                                            ^^^^^^ method not found in `MqttCodec`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
   = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
           `use tokio_util::codec::decoder::Decoder;`

error[E0599]: no method named `next` found for struct `Framed<tokio::net::TcpStream, MqttCodec>` in the current scope
  --> src/mqtt.rs:21:40
   |
21 |         while let Some(p) = self.inner.next().await {
   |                                        ^^^^ method not found in `Framed<tokio::net::TcpStream, MqttCodec>`

error[E0599]: no method named `start_send` found for struct `Framed<tokio::net::TcpStream, MqttCodec>` in the current scope
  --> src/mqtt.rs:27:20
   |
27 |         self.inner.start_send(p);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Framed<tokio::net::TcpStream, MqttCodec>`

warning: unused import: `tokio_util::codec::Decoder`
 --> src/mqtt.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use tokio_util::codec::Decoder;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unused import: `futures_sink::Sink`
 --> src/mqtt.rs:7:5
  |
7 | use futures_sink::Sink;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The compiler says that the `Decoder` trait is not in scope, but I use it. If I try the suggested import I find that the module `tokio_util::codec::decoder` is private. Based on the source `tokio_util::codec::decoder::Decoder` is reexported as `tokio_util::codec::Decoder`. Also if I read the docs correctly, `Framed` should implement `Sink` and `Stream` therefore it should have the `next` and `start_send` methods.

Relevant lines from Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.0.1", features = ["full"] }
tokio-util = { version = "0.6", features = ["full"] }
futures-sink = "0.3.9"
futures-core = "0.3.9"

mqtt-v5 = "0.1.1"
```

How can I get this to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of library incompatibilities that are causing some less-than-obvious error messages.

`mqtt-v5` [depends on `tokio-util^0.3`](https://crates.io/crates/mqtt-v5), which was written for `tokio` 0.2, not 1.0. You'll need to roll back to `tokio` 0.2 and `tokio-util` 0.3. This should fix the problem with `Decoder` and `Sink`.

Additionally, the `Stream` trait only provides `poll_next()`, which is the task-level stream method. `next()` is provided by the `StreamExt` trait, along with other convenience methods similar to those found in `Iterator`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to avoid these incompatibility issues? I'm thinking about some kind of cargo command to magically install right versions, or checks for incompatibilities?

Comment: So I tried the solution you suggested, Now Decoder and StreamExt are picked up, but the start_send method from Sink is not.

Comment: @laci37 If you specify only the major and minor versions (i.e. `x.y` rather than `x.y.z`), Cargo will automatically resolve a patch version `z` that's compatible for all libraries depending on `x.y` (if possible). Major version 0 is special in [semver](https://semver.org/), though, which means that Cargo can't always resolve these issues for `0.y` versions. I'd try changing the `futures` crates to just `0.3` and deleting `Cargo.lock`.

Comment: It seemed irrelevant, but I also want this app to have an HTTP api. turns out the serde = "1.0" dependency I use for JSON messes something up, If I comment it out, this module compiles.